# Using a var in regex

Tags: regex

I want to search for a specific (variable) word in a file.

```
private int read_inv(string file, string part) // part = SCRAP
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(invFolder + file + ".inv");


    string find = @"(?i)\bSCRAP\b"; // this return 3 like it should be
    string find = @"(?i)\b"+part+"\b"; // this return 0

    Regex r = new Regex(find);
    MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(text);
    int iCount = matches.Count;

    return matches.Count;
}
```

Comment: `@"(?i)\b"+part+@"\b"` ?

Comment: The duplicate question covers the fundamental mistake in your code. As a side-effect it might also start to work immediately, but that's impossible to predict because you did not say what inputs you have been using with your function.

Comment: Thanks TessellatingHeckler that did the trick.

Comment: No, it didn't, it works by accident, it will break again. You need to follow the steps in the other answer.

Comment: i dont understand why would i break ?
i tryed 7 different inputs and they all work.